# Why dragShadowBuilder doesn't show imageview?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am trying to use dragShadowBuilder(View view) constructor send to it ImageView not assosiated with the one I start draging from. ImageView img=new ImageView(this); img.setbackgroundresource(R.drawable.icon);
Why dragShadowBuilder doesn't show it during a drag?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ImageView is not being drawn until it is added to a layout.
I fixed this problem by drawing a Bitmap using extended ShadowBuilder:

```
public class LJDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

   private Bitmap image; // image to draw as a drag shadow

   public LJDragShadowBuilder(Bitmap _image) {
      super();
      image = _image;
   }

   public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
   {
      canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
   }

   public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint)
   {
      shadowSize.x = image.getWidth();
      shadowSize.y = image.getHeight();
      shadowTouchPoint.x = shadowSize.x / 2;
      shadowTouchPoint.y = shadowSize.y / 2;
   }
}
```